# Cloudera manager agent fails to install - nothing provides MySQL-python, python, python-psycopg2 needed by cloudera-manager-agent

Tags: mysql-python, cloudera, cloudera-manager, centos8

[image]

Hello,

I have a CentOS-8 linux cluster and I am trying to install Cloudera 6.2.1 on it. As you can see in the attached picture is failing on cloudera-manager-agent installation due to 3 conflicting requests. First one is MySQL-python. I tried to download that dependency, however they only have it for CentOS-7 and I am stuck here.

If I look into /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/ I know for sure I don't have the required MySQL-python. All I have is: mysql, mysql_connector_python-8.0.18-py2.7.egg-info and mysqlx

Do you have any advise for me?

Thank you very much!

Alin

Answer (score 0):

Cloudera is not supporting Centos 8.
You can try getting it via this, but I don't know if CM will recognize it:
https://centos.pkgs.org/8/mysql-connectors-x86_64/mysql-connector-python-8.0.18-1.el8.x86_64.rpm.html
python-psycopg2 is provided via https://centos.pkgs.org/8/postgresql-10-x86_64/python2-psycopg2-2.8.3-1.rhel8.x86_64.rpm.html

But to be honest, I would recommend going down to Centos 7.8 as long as they don't start supporting higher version.
Compatibility matrix is here:
https://docs.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/6/release-notes/topics/rg_os_requirements.html